# How to load hidden <div> on click

Tags: php, html, css

I am designing a front-end login/signup page by using html and materialize css.  The features that I am trying to include are:

- a tab view inside a card with an unordered list with two items:

  - "Login" (`<a href="#login">`), and
  - "SignUp" (`<a href="#signup">`).
- Two separate content areas with their own id: "login" and "signup"

My goal is to have the "id=login" content load when a user clicks `Login`, and likewise "id=signup" content to load on clicking `SignUp` but that's not working. As the image shows, both the tab view and both content "cards" are displayed.

---

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot]

---

This is my code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col l6 offset-l3 m8 offset-m2 s12">
        <div class="card-panel center">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

     <!-- Login content area -->

     <div class="col l6 offset-l3 m8 offset-m2 s12" id="login">
        <div class="card-panel center">

        </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Sign Up content area -->
        <div class="col l6 offset-l3 m8 offset-m2 s12" id="signup">
          <div class="card-panel center">

          </div>
        </div>
      <!-- row ends here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. Would you please include the relevant css for this html.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Please provide your PHP.

Comment: This is tagged PHP, but PHP isn't really relevant here. What you're describing is best done in Javascript. Are you using a JS framework? As @j08691 said, this looks like it might be Bootstrap.